# Modernizing our Saxon implementation

Tags: java, xml, xpath, saxon

I am undertaking a few upgrades on our project and am running into a lot of confusion with Saxon, due to how we implemented things in the past.

We created some utility classes for evaluating xpath expressions, and it seems like we probably used functionality from before the 9.x.x series. We leverage the utility classes in JUnit tests. We want to move from 9.5 and into 9.6, but are getting a few compilation issues.

We wrote a utility function to evaluate an XPath Expression

```
 ...
 proc.getUnderlyingConfiguration()
            .setSourceParserClass("com.boeing.cactus.xml.catalogs.CactusSchemaAwareXMLReader");

 evaluator = new XPathEvaluator(proc.getUnderlyingConfiguration());
 XPathExpression expr = evaluator.createExpression(expression);
 List<?> list = expr.evaluate(new DOMSource(node));
 return getStringFromXPathResult(list);
```

Where the `node` object is of type `org.w3c.dom.Node`

In Saxon 9.6, `expr.evaluate` no longer will take a `DOMSource`, it wants an `XPathDynamicContext`, which takes an implementer of the `Item` saxon interface.

We are having a similar problem where we are evaluating an XPath against an `InputSource`. In that case we are making a `StreamSource` from `javax.xml.transform.stream` out of the `InputSource object`. We then called a very similar `evaluate` implementation:

```
List<?> list = expr.evaluate(XmlTransformer.getSource(source));
```

I am really struggling to  figure out where a good simple walk-through is, or if our code is just so twisted, I need to revisit our tests and how they call to evaluate output.

Does anyone know a good simple "How to run simple XPath expressions with Saxon walk-through?" that is written towards the 9.x.x patterns? Or see exactly what I cannot figure out?

I know I could probably use a different API to run simple XPaths, but my predecessors made some things schema aware, and I want to be sure our unit tests match our underlying transformation engine.

Thanks for any help. I am sure this is super easy to perform.

Comment: If you move to the Saxon `s9api` API then it has good documentation at http://saxonica.com/html/documentation9.6/xpath-api/s9api-xpath.html and a sample on how to run against a DOM node in the file `S9APIExamples.java` available as part of the resources download at http://saxonica.com/download/saxon-resources9-6.zip.

Comment: What is the package name for class XPathEvaluator? There are two possibilities, net.sf.saxon.xpath and net.sf.saxon.sxpath. They represent different stages in the pre-9.0 evolution of the XPath API. These days you should almost certainly be using the s9api interface in preference: the old interfaces have little type safety and in some cases have problems with thread safety.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MartinHonnen and @MichaelKay . I will migrate towards that API. And for posterity it was the `net.sf.saxon.sxpath.XPathEvaluator;` I was using.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelKay. I ended up replicating what the library was doing inside the XPathEvaluator. Interestingly, when using iri-to-uri('c:\this\file\is\not\valid\file.txt') as the name of the file for an input source, it returned with the message in quotes in the newer API